# Error when returning pointer from method, but not when accessing the pointer directly. C++

Tags: c++

When I do this:

```cpp
int main() {

    Student *head = new Student();
    Student *second = new Student();

    head->S_getStudentPtr() = second; //Expression must be a modifiable Ivalue
    head->S_nextStudent = second;

    delete head;
    delete second;
    std::cout << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error when trying to return a pointer from method, the error message is shown in the comment.

However, when I am accessing the same pointer directly, it doesn't complain.

Here is the method:

```cpp
Student * Student::S_getStudentPtr() {
    S_nextStudent = new Student();
    return S_nextStudent;
}
```

I suspect that it is something with the method. But I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is the same situation as `int f() { return 1; } int main() { f() = 3; }`.

Comment: Okay. So I cannot actually return a pointer and then assign it to something else. Which means that I must use the pointer directly.

Comment: You can return a reference to a pointer if you want to be able to change it.

Comment: @Omar: Just in case: you can return a pointer and assign it to something else, but that would be written as `second = head->S_getStudentPtr()`. In C++, the thing you assign **to** appears on the left.

Comment: @Omar I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429071/65863) a *very similar* question just yesterday: [E0137 Expression must be a modifiable l-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428970/).  You really should search for existing questions before asking new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the return type as a reference to a pointer:

```cpp
Student*& Student::S_getStudentPtr() {
    S_nextStudent = new Student();
    return S_nextStudent;
}
```

However, **do not do this**. It's very prone to abuse. A better solution would be to create a real linked-list data structure using [`std::forward_list's interface`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) as a guide:

```cpp
class Student {
public:
    Student* head{};
    Student* next{};

    //Traverse the list and insert before the indicated index.
    Student* insert_before(std::size_t where, Student* s);

    //Traverse the list and insert after the indicated index.
    Student* insert_after(std::size_t where, Student* s);

    //Insert at the end
    void push_back(Student* s);

    //Check if the container is empty
    bool empty();
protected:
private:
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line `head->S_getStudentPtr() = second;` you are trying to put a pointer student (an r-value) into a method which is no l-value (l for left). This has to fail.

In order to propose a solution to your issue you need to give more information of what you want to do.

This might work though but I am not sure if it is what you want to do:
`second = head->S_getStudentPtr()`.

Comment: I was testing building a simple linked list that will grow to a multi linked list. Thank you, I am not sure if this will help me with that task.